# done is not a function

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working on securing apis by the use of jwt tokens. The goal here is to disallow a regular user from using POST request.
So, using the bearer token of a regular user and trying to make a post request returns me `done is not a function` in Postman. I tried the same with the bearer token of an admin but it still get the same error and I can't figure why it says that

code.js

```
const { expressjwt: expressJwt } = require("express-jwt");

function authJwt() {
  const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
  const api = process.env.API_URL;
  return expressJwt({
    secret: secret,
    algorithms: ["HS256"],
    isRevoked: isRevoked,
  }).unless({
    path: [
      { url: /\/api\/v1\/products(.*)/, methods: ["GET", "OPTIONS"] },
      { url: /\/api\/v1\/categories(.*)/, methods: ["GET", "OPTIONS"] },
      `${api}/users/login`,
      `${api}/users/register`,
      `${api}/users/reset-password`,
    ],
  });
}

async function isRevoked(req, payload, done) {
  if (!payload.isAdmin) {
    done(null, true);
  }
  done(null, false);
}

module.exports = authJwt;
```

Comment: [According to its documentation](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt#api), `isRevoked` should be a function that returns a promise, not one that expects a callback. If for whatever reason you can't modify `isRevoked`, wrap it with [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal).

Comment: I don't see how I could use a promise here. the payload contains the information I need for my if statement. Could you show me an example or send me a link to see something similar cuz i have no idea on how to fix this